# Ubuntu FFMPEG dynamic image file name

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I currently have a directory full of a variety of mp4 files, and I am currently able to loop through the whole directory and screen caps at every five second interval. Currently, the command names them starting at "00000001.png" and increments for the next screen cap, but I would like it to use the file name along with the numbers being appended. I attempted to re-use the "$file" variable, but I get an odd error from running the loop.

Command:

```
for file in /datadrive/video_repo/ffmpeg_tmp/*.mp4; do /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "$file" -r 0.5 /datadrive/image_repo/"${file%.}".%8d.png; done
```

But I get the following error at runtime:

```
Could not open file : /datadrive/image_repo//datadrive/video_repo/ffmpeg_tmp/testvideo00000001.png
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error
```

It looks like the output location is getting confused with the input for some reason. However, if I remove `"${file%.}"`, it runs fine.
(The reason I use "${file%.}", is because it uses the files name, and omits the extension).

Any help on this would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here: 
**/datadrive/image_repo/**/datadrive/video_repo/ffmpeg_tmp/testvideo00000001.png

You're using the path TWICE, so he finds the path and add again here: **/datadrive/image_repo/"${file%.}".%8d.png** but your ${file%.} is already **/datadrive/image_repo/**

```
for file in /datadrive/video_repo/ffmpeg_tmp/*.mp4; 
    do /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "$file" -r 0.5 "${file%.}".%8d.png; 
done
```

Comment: I thought I understood that "file" is the variable that holds the names of all the mp4 files in  /datadrive/video_repo/ffmpeg_tmp/, and that I needed to specify a different output directory to have the images placed inside /datadrive/image_repo/. Otherwise there is no mention of the desired output directory. But worst case, I just add another step to transfer all png files to the separate directory after.

Comment: I tried out this comment, and it worked. However, after I cleared out the ffmpeg_tmp folder to test it a second time, I ran into the same error I mentioned above. (all the video files were added back in before I ran the test.)
[image2 @ 0x1948d20] Could not open file : /datadrive/video_repo/ffmpeg_tmp/test_video.mp4.00000001.png
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error

Where it seems it's still taking the output file, and using it as the input.

Comment: how did you clear the folder? did you removed the .mp4 or the .png? paste here the command used

Comment: btw, this guy got an error similar to yours, check it here >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774853/ffmpeg-av-interleaved-write-frame-operation-not-permitted?rq=1

Comment: I went to clear all of the files from the directory to test the whole procedure. I used "sudo rm -r video_repo/ffmpeg_tmp" and then remade the directory.

Comment: try use just "rm -rf video_repo/ffmpeg_tmp", if you use sudo you'll change the permission of the directory unintentional

Comment: I honestly can't believe that using sudo caused the permission of the directory to change, and caused the error output to look like it was misreading the input for output. Thank you very much, it's working again!

Comment: I have a very big problem with sudo haha I always use sudo to rm files but then it goes to trash with super user permission and I can't empty it. Anyway, i'm glad I could help.